# Is there a way to keep a document library from replicatiing on another copied page?

Tags: 2013, document, library, replication

Say you copy a Page from your Publishing Site in order to use it as a Template/Shell; That first page then, has a Document Library inserted into it. The 2nd Page was meant to have its own new Document Library(but keep the shell) but unfortunately it duplicates whatever happens on the original "copied" Page. Is there a way to break this replication so that the duplicated page can have it's own Document Library?

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you is to create a Page Layout. Inside Page Layouts you can place Web Part zones, which you can fill in as you create new pages.

This will ensure the new pages have the similar look and feel and have its own library views.